# "Moving a directory into itself" error in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, directory

I have an application which sorts files upon receiving the path to the folder containing the files.
However, there's a line of code where I'm supposedly moving a directory into itself, but I can't see how that's happening since I'm doing the same thing with the other parts and they aren't resulting in an error.

Here's the part containing the error.

the part resulting in an error is the last block, where I'm trying to move other files into "Other" folder.

I tried changing up the destination in the shutil.move() but the error is persisting.

```
os.chdir(path)
new_folder = "Sorted Files"
os.makedirs(new_folder)
path_2 = path+"/"+new_folder
os.chdir(path_2)
new_folder_doc = "Documents"
new_folder_texts = "Texts"
new_folder_images = "Images"
new_folder_other = "Other"
os.makedirs(new_folder_doc)
os.makedirs(new_folder_texts)
os.makedirs(new_folder_images)
os.makedirs(new_folder_other)


for file in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

        #  Sorting files
    if file_path.endswith('.png') or file_path.endswith('.gif') or file_path.endswith('.bmp') or\
            file_path.endswith('.jpg') or file_path.endswith('.jpeg') is True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_images)
        continue
    if file_path.endswith('.txt') or file_path.endswith('.ini') or file_path.endswith('.log') is True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_texts)
        continue
    if file_path.endswith('.pdf') or file_path.endswith('.docx') or file_path.endswith('.doc') or\
            file_path.endswith('.xls') or file_path.endswith('.xlsx') or file_path.endswith('.csv') is True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_doc)
        continue
    if file_path.endswith('.docx') or file_path.endswith('.txt') or file_path.endswith('.bmp') or \
            file_path.endswith('.png') or file_path.endswith('.ini') or file_path.endswith('.log') \
            or file_path.endswith('.gif') or file_path.endswith('.doc') or file_path.endswith('.dir') \
            or file_path.endswith('.xls') or file_path.endswith('.xlsx') or file_path.endswith('.csv') \
            or file_path.endswith('.jpg') or file_path.endswith('.jpeg') or file_path.endswith('.pdf') is not True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_other)
        continue
```

Comment: Can you use either a debugger or `print` statements to see what `move` is causing the problem?

Comment: you have to change your current working directory back to `path`, before looping over the files (so after all the `os.makedirs()`), because you are still in `path_2` (`Sorted Files` dir) and not in `path` before moving the files to the `Other` directory.

Comment: the shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_other)  is the problem

Comment: @Gandhi but if I change it back to path, I am met with an error which says can't create a folder when it already exists (even though the folder didn't exist before running the code)

Comment: `os.listdir` lists both files and directories. In your last block, you try to move every file/directory that does not end with ".pdf" which is true for the "Other" directory.

Comment: @juhat that makes it clearer on why the error is persisting

Comment: So what would fix the problem here?

Comment: Perform sorting only to fiiles. Use os.path.isfile to check if it is a file

Comment: @juhat could you possibly show what the code should look like? I've been trying to do what you said for the past half an hour but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` lists both files and directories. In your last block, you try to move every file/directory that does not end with ".pdf" which is true for the "Other" directory.

To fix it in your code, you could perform sorting only to files, not directories. You could easily skip directories in your for-loop by adding the following code to check if "file_path"-variable actually refers to a file or not:

```
if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
    continue
```

Also, you might want to double-check your ".endswith"-conditions. `is True` and `is not True` there only applies to the last condition, not all of them (which I think is what you're looking for).